# Getting remote data with angularjs without CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

Is there by any means one can access remote data using restful api without CORS enabled on the remote server.

I'm asking this because I'm trying to access a remote data via an API with angularjs and I've tried all my best can't get seem to load the data. I always get this from Chrome

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Below is my script

```
var auth = $base64.encode("dHNxdWFpbm9vOlFoYXNoZW0xMjM="), 
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + auth};

$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://mywebapp.com/Cust?account_number=010104051681', 
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic dHNxdWFpbm9vOlFoYXNoZW0xMjM=' }
}).success
(function(data){
   $scope.user=data;
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

so without CORS enabled, its there a way I can get the data via JS or unless I enable CORS I can't get the data

Comment: If you control mywebapp.com why not enable CORS for the calling origin?

Comment: Of course. Run your own server that implements jsonp or cors or is local and have said server get the data instead. easy.

Comment: You can't share a cross-origin resource without enabling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, no.

Comment: The server is not mine. I just used that URL as a sample

Comment: You can use a reverse proxy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Answer (score 0):

You can make a reverse proxy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy. In short:

1. AngularJS client calls Your backend server
2. Your backend server calls http://mywebapp.com/Cust?account_number=010104051681
3. Your backend server get response
4. Your backend server sends that response back to the AngularJS client.